# HTML: Prioritize onclick over href

Tags: html, onclick, href

I would like to know if it's possible to have both onclick and href on a  html tag and priorize the onclick over the href.
I just want to have a href for robots/oldbrowsers accessibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just return `false` from the `onclick` handler and it will prevent the default action which is that the browser is opening the link in the `href`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your JavaScript to be unobtrusive, you can bind your events by using `addEventListener` instead of using the `onclick` property of the link.

When you add an event listener you can define an `event` parameter which has a method to suppress the default behavior of the element. In this case, it will stop the browser from navigating to the `href` of the link.

```
myLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* onclick logic goes here */ 
}, false);
```

or in jQuery . . .

```
jQuery('#myLink').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    /* onclick logic goes here */ 
});
```